# How can I make the coupon code field in commerce mandatory?

Tags: 7, forms, commerce

Using D7 commerce coupon/discount modules. I need to make the coupon field mandatory. Every order needs a coupon code entered.

There is no standard "required" checkbox on the field and I tried using conditional fields module to no avail.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Does every order need to be accompanied by a Coupon code? As in, you can't order without a coupon code?


Or do you just want to make sure the coupon code field isn't blank when people hit the "Add coupon" button?

Comment: They always need to use a coupon code for every order.

Comment: Why use the coupon module at all? Could you not simply add a required field to the order type? Or are there all kinds of coupons with all kinds of discounts?

Comment: There are multiple affiliates that sell a product through their own systems that issue a user with a coupon code with varying levels of discounts. The coupons and amounts vary too much to go the route you mention. However a coupon code is required for all purchases.

Comment: I understand. I'll see if I can come up with something.

Comment: Sounds great. Thank you.

Comment: Can this be done with a hook_form_alter and marking that field required?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must do this in a `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`.

You wouldn't use `hook_form_alter()` unless you are checking on a dynamic form ID. In this case it's better to use `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`.

The reason for this, is that `hook_form_alter()` is called on every form render and `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` is only called when that specific form is being rendered.

Add this code to your `.module` file to make the field required:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MY_MODULE_form_commerce_checkout_form_checkout_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (!empty($form['commerce_coupon']['coupon_code'])) {
    $form['commerce_coupon']['coupon_code']['#required'] = TRUE;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the better answer, due to the - justified - use of `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter`

Answer (score 4):

You can do that by Implements `hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter` but that would allow passing the step if the user enters any random string inside the coupon field.

To avoid this confusion you need to use the form alter to make coupon field required and also add custom validation to check if the coupon is valid.

if the coupon is not valid, then the user will stay in the step and will get the same error message provided by the commerce coupon module.

I assume your custom module name is '**CUSTOM**'

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function CUSTOM_form_commerce_checkout_form_checkout_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (!empty($form['commerce_coupon']['coupon_code'])) {
    // Set code as required.
    $form['commerce_coupon']['coupon_code']['#required'] = TRUE;
    $form['buttons']['continue']['#validate'][] = 'my_custom_coupon_validate';
  }
}

/**
 * Custom coupon validate.
 */
function my_custom_coupon_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $code = $form_state['input']['commerce_coupon']['coupon_code'];
  $order = $form_state['order'];

    $coupon = commerce_coupon_redeem_coupon_code($code, $order, $error);
    if ($coupon) {
      // Reload the order so it is not out of date.
      $order = commerce_order_load($order->order_id);
      // Recalculate discounts.
      commerce_cart_order_refresh($order);
    }
    else {
      form_set_error('coupon_code',$error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hook form alter isn’t the preferred solution unless you are checking for dynamic form ID.

Comment: @Jdrupal thanks for suggesting that, I change the implementation.